# In a tree, calculate distance of each node from root, using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

Given a tree like this

```
     a
    / \
   b   c
  / \
 d   e
 |
 f
```

i want to write a Cypher query that returns me:

```
startPoint: f, endPoint: a, path: [{f,3},{d,2},{b,1},{a,0}]
startPoint: d, endPoint: a, path: [{d,2},{b,1},{a,0}]
startPoint: e, endPoint: a, path: [{e,2},{b,1},{a,0}]
startPoint: b, endPoint: a, path: [{b,1},{a,0}]
startPoint: c, endPoint: a, path: [{c,1},{a,0}]
```

(in any particular order of startPoint)

Comment: Please specify the problem you are facing in doing what you 'want' to do and visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how you can make your question more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your relationships are directed "downwards" in the tree, and every node has an `id` property, this should work:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b {id:'a'})
WITH a, b, NODES(p) AS pts, LENGTH(p) AS n
RETURN
  a.id AS startPoint,
  b.id AS endPoint,
  REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, n) | s + {id: (pts[i]).id, depth: n-i}) AS path;
```

Here is sample output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| startPoint | endPoint | path                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "b"        | "a"      | [{id=b, depth=1},{id=a, depth=0}]                                 |
| "d"        | "a"      | [{id=d, depth=2},{id=b, depth=1},{id=a, depth=0}]                 |
| "f"        | "a"      | [{id=f, depth=3},{id=d, depth=2},{id=b, depth=1},{id=a, depth=0}] |
| "e"        | "a"      | [{id=e, depth=2},{id=b, depth=1},{id=a, depth=0}]                 |
| "c"        | "a"      | [{id=c, depth=1},{id=a, depth=0}]                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```